# What happened if I put the PBS script into the background?

Tags: playonlinux

Please see this PBS job:

```
 #!/bin/csh
 #PBS -N SumUniqah.MHB
 #PBS -q hotel
 #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
 #PBS -l walltime=168:00:00
 #PBS -o hapinfo2mhl.log
 #PBS -e hapinfo2mhl.err
 cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
 perl ~/bin/hapinfo2mhb.pl SP.Hap.SumUniqaa 0.5 > MHB.RD90up80.r0.5-aa.bed &
```

I found when I put a **&** at the end of the perl script, the pbs job will be error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you need ...

```
(perl ~/bin/hapinfo2mhb.pl SP.Hap.SumUniqaa 0.5 > MHB.RD90up80.r0.5-aa.bed) &
```

to put the command into background.